# Library to access BeagleBone Black (3.8 Kerne - Angstrom)

Tags: c++, python, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack

I saw that there is a very nice python library ([PyBBIO](https://github.com/alexanderhiam/PyBBIO)) for direct Control of the BBB using mmap on /dev/mem/ (granted not for the muxing). With some goodies like Webmonitor etc. Unfortunatly this library is not running on the 3.8 Kernel.

Are there any viable alternatives in python/c/c++ using mmap? I saw some but non was as complete as the mentioned PyBBIO.

I did successfully try the solution explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13124271/driving-beaglebone-gpio-through-dev-mem). But implementing everything (UART/PWM) sounds like it would be something to difficult for me to do...

yours
magu_

Answer (score 0):

as mentionned here : https://github.com/alexanderhiam/PyBBIO/issues/24 you should try [this one](https://github.com/adafruit/adafruit-beaglebone-io-python) which support 3.8 kernels

Answer (score 0):

chek this out i have explained steps to use GPIO using dev/mem

http://chiragnagpal.github.io/examples.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  That looks like a useful blog post but could you summarize the answer here?  Thanks!

Comment: I'd also like to welcome you to [so]. The reason why we prefer that answers aren't _just_ a link to another site is that links can expire, people may not be able to access links (for example, filtering at work has blocked your site) and it introduces yet another page to go on to find the answer. If the link breaks, it effectively is nothing, and becomes useless. Of course, you can still give a link if you need to explain things in a significant amount of detail (i.e. very lengthy), but a good summary of what that link contains is very useful. For more information, see [answer]. Thank you!