# Can hardware registers be mapped to userspace

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, powerpc

I'm developing an LED driver on Freescale MPC8306. In driver code, I do ioremap on GPIO registers and call remap_pfn_range upon the remapped GPIO register address, then, call mmap in userspace to map the GPIO register to userspace. I haven't done this before and I want to know if this method work or not. Can some help me? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Much simpler to use the `/sys/class/gpio` interface if what you want is userspace. Why re-invent the wheel, see http://elinux.org/GPIO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easier way would probably just to `mmap` the relevant offset of `/dev/mem` in your userspace program directly. This allows you to access the physical memory layout by seeking into it.

AFAIK, this is what the RaspberryPi developers have done to make GPIO memory mapped I/O registers available to userspace programs.

Comment: With the *big* caveat that some things aren't safe to do in userspace unless you're sure you're the *only* thing doing accesses, e.g. a read-modify-write of a register. (It's more fun on the rPi since you're supposed to use a memory barrier when switching peripherals, which hopefully kernel code will do; other userspace threads might not be so forgiving.)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `/dev/mem` interface for accessing the GPIO registers. A good reference for controlling LEDs via GPIOs on another embedded board is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13124271/driving-beaglebone-gpio-through-dev-mem).